# How can i make the loader bar in the top of page in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make the loading bar in the top of page when its loaded. How can I do that? I have no clue on how to do it and make it dynamic when the page is loaded.

Comment: [react-top-loading-bar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-top-loading-bar) is a npm package which you can use to create the top loading bar in react, on this site you can see the docs of the package and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a state as this:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
```

Then, you can show a loading bar in JSX defaultly:

```
<span style={isLoading ? {display: 'block'} : {display: 'none'}}>
  Loading...
</span>
```

After, you can find out when the component has been loaded by using `useEffect` and square brackets:

```
useEffect(() => {

  setIsLoading(false);

}, []);
```

That's it! When the component was loaded, the `isLoading` is set to `false` and loading bar is not shown anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a **LoadingState** that will Show LoadingScreen until data is fetched and once fetched it will Show relevant Data.

```
function App() {
   const [laoding, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
}


React.useEffect(() => {
   fetchYourDataHere().
   setLoading(false)
  // This get called every time components Load
  // Once we have our data we can set loading to false
},[depsHere])

if(loading) {
   return <LoadingScreen />
}

return (<div> Your Regular Component </div>)
```

**UseEffect** is a Hook that can be used to fetch data at Every Component load. call your data fetching function in this and then set Loading State as False.